# BSplineFunction and its derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, splines

Hi I am trying to use curve fit some data using the `BSplineFunction`. I haven't been using *Mathematica* long, so my questions might be quite basic.

```
pts = {{0, 645.01`}, {5, 645.445`}, {10, 645.622`}, {15, 
646.048`}, {20, 646.475`}, {25, 646.934`}, {30, 647.496`}, {35, 
648.296`}, {40, 649.095`}, {45, 651.485`}, {50, 652.017`}, {55, 
652.611`}, {60, 653.268`}, {65, 653.924`}, {70, 654.231`}, {75, 
654.473`}, {80, 654.8`}, {85, 655.136`}, {90, 655.146`}, {95, 
655.126`}, {100, 656.136`}, {105, 655.116`}, {110, 655.126`}, {115,
655.106`}, {120, 655.116`}, {125, 655.096`}}
```

using;

```
SP = BSplineFunction[pts]
```

I am trying to find out if there is a way to expand this function and look at its individual parts over a specified range within my dataset.

I am also trying to look at the derivative of the function at a specific points by using.

```
SP'[pts1 = Table[{i, SP'[i]}, {i, 0, 1, .1}];
```

Is this the right method to get the derivative? If it isn't, I would appreciate it if someone could point in the right direction. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
SP = BSplineFunction[pts]
dsp[t_] = D[SP[t], t]   (* equivalently use SP'[t] *) 
Show[ 
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.01], Point /@ pts}],
   ParametricPlot[SP[t], {t, 0, 1}],
   Graphics[Arrow /@ Table[{SP[t], SP[t] + .1 dsp[t] }, {t, 0, 1, .1}]],
   AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

The bspline is a continuous function of the parameter t and does not generally hit your points so its not clear what you mean to look at individual parts.

Edit a bit of qualification on that last point, you can identify a region of influence on the curve associated with each control point. Showing that gets a bit hairy though.

Comment: I guess the OP needs `Interpolation` and you can accommodate that possibility in your answer. However the graphics is cool :) so +1...

Comment: yes, I was going to say the BSpline is likely not the best way to 'fit' that data, but maybe he has some reason..